# How can we add SSRS Reporting web part in share point?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

Hi I am using Windows 7 32 bit and I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and business intelligence on my PC. I couldn't find the web part of reporting services... Actually I have to upload my reports built in report builder. Now I have to upload these reports to share point site as webparts. The possible solution was to add SSRS report webpart but I am unable to install. Please guide me to what I am missing.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SSRS in native mode you have to install the WebParts. SharePoint Package with SSRS WebParts can be found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Reporting Services\SharePoint
```

Instruction how to install WebParts can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx) in Installing Web Parts section. Also I suggest to use SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode which enables some cool features (like subscriptions).